# Como puedo retornar la url de acceso de un archivo generado en el servidor con Node

Tags: nodejs, pdf

Estoy generando archivos pdf en Node Js, se estan guardando exitosamente, mi duda ahora es como puedo acceder a ellos para visualizarlos, obtener un link de los mismos, como https://dominio/reportes/reporte.pdf

Comment: Usas alguna base de datos y framework para servidor? o netamente es NodeJS para manejar archivos?

Comment: Mysql, alli guardo el nombre del documento, que se genero y estoy usando express

Comment: Haz realizado alguna petición de tipo `GET` para obtener las respectivas urls o locaciones del documento?

Comment: Creo ya resolvi, aplicando una ruta statics a mi app express y accediendo mediante ella al archivo

Comment: Javier, lo que has comentado debes ponerlo _como respuesta_, y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer). Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.